# How to view WSDL on a JAX-WS web service running under Glassfish?

Tags: java, tomcat, wsdl, glassfish, jax-ws

How can I view the WSDL of my JAX-WS web service if I'm running it under Glassfish? I know I can generate the WSDL file using wsgen, but I'm want to know if I can have a runtime WSDL on Glassfish?

I've tried running my web service on Tomcat and I was able to get a runtime WSDL by accessing the URL pattern I specified on web.xml. However, since I don't have a web.xml on my JAX-WS web service on Glassfish, I'm not sure how I'm going to access my WSDL.

Comment: What JAX-WS implementation do you use?

Comment: I'm using the default JAX-WS on Glassfish. For the Tomcat, I downloaded my JAX-WS jars at http://jax-ws.java.net/ . Are they using the same implementation? I'm confused with Metro and the original JAX-WS from Java. I know I'm running my other web service on Glassfish which can be downloaded on Oracle's site. So I'm thinking that the JAXWS from Glassfish is the Java's implementation. However, on the link I provided, you can see that Metro is a subclass of Glassfish. Is Metro an alias of Java's implementation of JAX-WS?

Comment: They are the same, Glassfish uses the web service implementations from [Metro](http://metro.java.net/). Metro is the parent project for a number of Web Service related projects including the reference implementation of JAX-WS.

Comment: @NickWilson: Thanks! I also posted this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670261/metro-vs-javas-jax-ws since I think it is a new topic. Can you answer the question on the link I provided? I'm still confused on something. Why is Glassfish using Metro when Java has its own JAX-WS implementation bundled on JDK 6? I thought Glassfish is the standard J2EE server for Java since it's hosted at Oracle site? Please answer my question on the link I provided. Thank again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you know the endpoint URL of your web service you should be able to view the runtime WSDL by appending `?wsdl` to the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks! Found it. It's my className + "Service" + "?wsdl". I saw the link also inside Glassfish console. I'm having a problem the accessing Glassfish console earlier so I wasn't able to see it. Thanks again!

Comment: Also if there is an WebService annotation with serviceName parameter wsdl can be figured as - serviceName + "/" +  className + "/" + "?wsdl"

Answer (score 0):

1. **Start** the **GlassFish** server (E.g.: from the Servers tab in Eclipse).
2. Navigate to **GlassFish Console** (E.g.: http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf)
3. On the left side, click on **Applications**
4. On the right side, click on the **project name**
5. In the **Modules and Components section**, click on **View Endpoint** in the Action column
6. Click on the **WSDL** value (E.g.: `/Test/MyClassService?wsdl` - now you are in http://localhost:4848/common/applications/webServiceWsdl.jsf?appName=Test&wsdl=%2FTest%2FMyClassService%3Fwsdl)
7. Now you can 2 see links (for **HTTP** and HTTPS). Click on the first one (E.g.: http://localhost.localdomain:8080/Test/MyClassService?wsdl) and you will see the **WSDL** file.