# Where I can find all wsdl in glassfish?

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669835/how-to-view-wsdl-on-a-jax-ws-web-service-running-under-glassfish) but is there a tool or url in glassfish where I can find list of all generated WSDL? (It is not very good to type className + "Service?wsdl" as for dozen classes with @WebService annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by going into the admin console (I believe this is `localhost:4848` by default) and looking at all the items under the Web Services tree on the left.  If you click on one, there will be a link to view the wsdl in the details.

Comment: I could not find Web Servie tree in GlassFish 3.1.2.2, but it is possible to see list of all Web Service enpoints, Servlets and Beans  (Stateless and Statefull).

Look at tree in the left, find item "Applications" expand it and click on your WebApplication. You will see the table, in action column you will find "View Endpoint" links in rows that belongs to Web Service classes.

Comment: So after click "View Endpoint" you will go to enpoint description page with generated wsdl link.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

You can consider using GlassFish 4.2.1 (as in my case - **java-8-oracle**, **Glassfish 4.2.1** and **Eclipse Oxygen**). I've discovered some **problems with GlassFish 4.0** and namely that the XML schema would not be interpreted and visualized by the server, followed by a server response of 500. In the log files I discovered that there were some issues with the secure connection with the server. The tester would not run as well.

The following example is running under the configuration I've mentioned above.

You can do this by going to http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf and clicking on the Application menu, on the left hand side dropdown menu. There you chose your application[image: Go to application]

[image: Application example]

As you see, I've set up a basic example called GlassTest. When you click on it, you get yet another menu. Here you chose **View Endpoint**
[image: View Endpoint]
The **WSDL** hyperlink gets you the information on the web service endpoint and the schema.[image: Web service endpoint]

Hope this helps!